# Draw an airport runway in Tikz with perspective

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, technical-drawing

I am trying to generate an airport runway in TikZ with the markings and with a slight perspective. The solution I obtain using a for loop seems quite complex and not very clean.

Is there an efficient way to draw the runway markings slanted? Maybe, by drawing everything flat and then slant the entire drawing?

Here is a MWE, drawing the runway with slanted markings!

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1mm,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]

%% Runway plot
% Runway outer boundaries
\draw[-] (0,-0.5) -- (+15,-0.5) -- (+15.5,-1) -- (+0.5,-1) -- cycle;
% Center line
%\draw[dashed,dash pattern=on 15pt off 5pt,line width=1.5pt] (+0.5,-0.75) -- (+15,-0.75);
\foreach \i in {1,...,24}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{\i * 0.6};
    \draw[-,fill] (\x+0.375,-0.73) --++ (15pt,0) --++ (0.25pt,-0.25pt) --++ (-15pt,0) -- cycle;
}
% Threshold
\draw[-,fill] (0.25,-0.6) --++ (15pt,0) --++ (1.5pt,-1.5pt) --++ (-15pt,0) -- cycle;
\draw[-,fill] (0.5,-0.85) --++ (15pt,0) --++ (1.5pt,-1.5pt) --++ (-15pt,0) -- cycle;
\draw[-,fill] (14.4,-0.6) --++ (15pt,0) --++ (1.5pt,-1.5pt) --++ (-15pt,0) -- cycle;
\draw[-,fill] (14.65,-0.85) --++ (15pt,0) --++ (1.5pt,-1.5pt) --++ (-15pt,0) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you for your help

Romain

Comment: I wonder why you don't prefer to draw it on Inkscape and insert it as a figure? Also, by the way, this is not real perspective but rather an `orthogonal camera' projection, in 3D program parlance.

Answer (score 6):

You can draw as usual:

[image]

and then use the `xslant` option to get slanted picture.

[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xslant=-.8]
\def\a{15.5}
\def\step{5mm}
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (\a,1);
\draw[dashed,dash pattern=on \step off \step] (.5,.5)--(\a-.5,.5);
\fill 
(.5,.7) rectangle +(\step,.1)
(.5,.3) rectangle +(\step,-.1)
(\a-.5,.7) rectangle +(-\step,.1)
(\a-.5,.3) rectangle +(-\step,-.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution using the `3d` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
\coordinate (s) at (0,0);
\coordinate (f) at (15.3,0);
\draw ([yshift=-1cm]s) rectangle ([yshift=1cm]f);
\draw[dash pattern=on 3mm off 2mm,dash phase=3mm,very thick,gray] ([xshift=3mm]s) -- ([xshift=-3mm]f);
\fill ([shift={(3mm,3mm)}]s) rectangle +(4mm,2mm);
\fill ([shift={(3mm,-3mm)}]s) rectangle +(4mm,-2mm);
\fill ([shift={(-3mm,3mm)}]f) rectangle +(-4mm,2mm);
\fill ([shift={(-3mm,-3mm)}]f) rectangle +(-4mm,-2mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]